# What is necessary to implement monero into Bitcoin trezor?

Tags: development-roadmap, trezor

What is necessary to implement monero into Bitcoin trezor? And what could we expect in the future, as the developement moves on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5d24ej/update_on_the_monero_trezor_firmware/) by Trezor developer:

> 1. provide instructions how to build trezor-xmr
> 2. add monero messages to trezor-common
> 3. add monero crypto to trezor-crypto
> 4. add monero code to trezor-mcu
> 5. add monero stuff to python-trezor (aka trezorctl)

Appareantly there was a conflict between the Trezor developer (stikac) and Monero developer (NoodleDoodle) about who should do this work.

Quoting the [Trezor developer from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5d24ej/update_on_the_monero_trezor_firmware/da18i5r/):

> The work he's done is something I appreciate, but the current state is
>   impossible to merge into our code. Doing that extra mile will require
>   an extra effort, which NoodleDoodle is not willing to do and
>   unfortunately, we at TREZOR, have no capacity doing this, as we are
>   working on TREZORv2 at the moment (while still maintaining current set
>   of features for TREZORv1). In the (now deleted) discussion I
>   criticized bounty programs as something that rarely leads to quality
>   code and does not motivate the developers to produce quality code,
>   because they don't have to maintain it later (which is quite critical
>   for cryptography in general and what was taken too personally by
>   NoodleDoodle).

Comment: I hope that some monero dev will do this job, even if it means raising more money for this task and I hope he will keep maintaining this repository. I really believe in open-source trezor firmware and what they are doing.

Comment: I feel the same way

Answer (score 4):

From what I know, NoodleDoodle is still currently working on improving the firmware to be able to work with RingCT transactions.  It is still "technically" in a testing phase though; and you can see progress being made.  You can test out the firmware by downloading from either [here](https://forum.getmonero.org/4/academic-and-technical/2495/experimental-trezor-firmware-testing) on the official forum, or getting it from [here](https://github.com/NoodleDoodleNoodleDoodleNoodleDoodleNoo/monero/commit/5f96f277c63b40b34c8e39c14ab65faf5794d9f2) on github.

As for the first part of your question, I believe you meant to ask what is the current status with Monero's integration into the official trezor firmware.  As for that, that's still up in the air.  There are no more links to the actual conversation that took place (I think?); but from how I understood it, there was a disagreement of some sort between NoodleDoodle and one of the head guys at Trezor who was working on integrating Monero.

Anyway, long story short, the upstream merge of NoodleDoodle's firmware has been halted.  On the bright side, there are other hardware wallet companies such as Ledger willing to help out.  You can read more of what went on recently [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5cblwf/ledger_nano_s_hardware_support/) on the current thread about the situation on /r/Monero.