# Pin Entropy of Trezor versus Ledger Nano S

Tags: security, trezor, entropy, ledger

There have been discussions of adding hardware support for Monero, specifically for Trezor and Ledger wallet.

How much more entropy does a 9 digit pin (Trezor) offer compared to a 4 digit pin (Ledger Nano S)?

Will the 8 digit pin option planned for [Ledger Bue](https://www.ledgerwallet.com/products/9-ledger-blue) also be made available for the Nano S in a future update?

Besides pin length what are some of the other primary differences in securing Monero (with [unofficial Trezor firmware](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2724/61) now and official firmware for both platforms when available) on Trezor compared to Ledger Nano S

Does either wallet support:

1. Passwords in addition to a pin?
2. Timeouts between pin/password attempts?
3. Wiping of device after a certain number of incorrect pin/passwords attempts?
4. Support for dummy accounts?
5. Any other notable security features that differentiate one hardware wallet from the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How much more entropy does a 9 digit pin (Trezor) offer compared to a 4 digit pin (Ledger Nano S)?

Given entropy per symbol (0-9) is 3.322 [<sup>source</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength#Random_passwords) you get 13.328 for 4 digits and 29.898 for 9 digits. Thus you get 16.57 more bits of entropy with a 9 digit pin than a 4 digit pin.

With regards to all your other sub questions, the products are constantly evolving so it doesn't seem appropriate to do a tear-down comparison except to say *official* Ledger support for Monero looks far closer than the Trezor.